# Delete and Rerender Widget immediately

Tags: flutter

DESIRED OUTCOME: I have a listview which displays a list of todos. I like to implement a delete function which will trigger when the user clicks on a 'delete' icon button. I also like the listview to rerender automatically which removes the deleted todo.

PRESENT: I am able to delete the todo but the widget doesn't rerender to display the updated listview (which will remove the deleted todo)

What is the best practice to implement this auto rerender to show the updated listview? I do not want to navigate to a new page.

Thank you

Below are my codes

The link https://github.com/myhendry/flutter to my full code

**taskCard.dart**

```
      ScopedModelDescendant(
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
          return IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              onPressed: () {
                model.deleteTask(task.id);
                //  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/updateTask/${task.id}');
              });
        },
      ),
```

**scoped-models/connected_products.dart**

```
  Future<bool> deleteTask(String selectedTaskId) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    try {
      await http.delete(
          'https://manager1-ae03e.firebaseio.com/tasks/$selectedTaskId.json?auth=${_authenticatedUser.token}');
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. I just call fetchTasks() after the task has been deleted. I am not sure if this is good practise. If anyone has a better way, please feel free to share with me. Thanks

My code below. Hope it helps those facing the same problem

```
      ScopedModelDescendant(
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, MainModel model) {
          return IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              onPressed: () {
                model.deleteTask(task.id);
                model.fetchTasks();
                //  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/updateTask/${task.id}');
              });
        },
      ),
```